# What format does an .htpassword file use for checking passwords?

Tags: authentication

So I've gotten to the point of creating a login system.  I've considered having it store hashed passwords in a database that are written to an .htpassword file outside public view on a server.  I can do this, but a problem occurs when I try to verify the password against the database or the password input by a user.  It appears that the password in the .htpassword file is verified using some particular format I'm not aware of...meaning I can't just use Password A === Password B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Apache's documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html):

> `htpasswd` is used to create and update the flat-files used to store usernames and password for basic authentication of HTTP users.

Examples:

> `htpasswd /usr/local/etc/apache/.htpasswd-users jsmith`
>
> Adds or modifies the password for user jsmith. The user is prompted
>   for the password. The password will be encrypted using the modified
>   Apache MD5 algorithm. If the file does not exist, `htpasswd` will do
>   nothing except return an error.
>
> `htpasswd -c /home/doe/public_html/.htpasswd jane`
>
> Creates a new file and stores a record in it for user jane. The user
>   is prompted for the password. If the file exists and cannot be read,
>   or cannot be written, it is not altered and `htpasswd` will display a
>   message and return an error status.
>
> `htpasswd -db /usr/web/.htpasswd-all jones Pwd4Steve`
>
> Encrypts the password from the command line (Pwd4Steve) using the
>   `crypt()` algorithm, and stores it in the specified file.

This is misleading as the password is not encrypted but rather hashed, and bad because it's using md5 ([iterated 1000 times](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html)) by default. You should use `htpasswd -B` to use bcrypt instead.

Comment: Yes, as soon as you said MD5, I cringed.  It looks like MD5 is likely what I'm running up against.  I'll have to try htpasswd -B.